# Create a button programatically in differrent class swift

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to swift and trying to create a UIButton programmatically. I have two classes. I am creating a button in one class and calling that method from another class.

**class viewcontroller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let renderobj = render()
    renderobj.sign()
}
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
}
```

**class render**

```
import UIKit

class render: UIViewController {
  func sign() {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
  }

  func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
  }
}
```

But no button is created. If I put the `UIButton` code inside `viewDidLoad()` , it works. I want the button to be created in a function of different class. Is it possible to do so ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You are creating a new instance of render class in your viewDidLoad. You should use the one which is already added to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func sign() -> UIButton
{
   let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
   button.backgroundColor = .green
   button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
   return button 
}
```

> After returning that button you can add it in your calling view controller view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let renderobj = render()
let button = renderobj.sign()
self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing this

```
let renderobj = render()
```

And after calling this function, a new button is initialized and added to the view of `render` view controller.

```
renderobj.sign()
```

But `renver` view controller is only initialized and its view is not added to current view controller which is `ViewController`

If you want to show `render` controller, then present it like usual. If you want to add that button to your `ViewController` then either declare a button variable and access it or return it in `sign()` function

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a lack of understanding around the concepts of a `UIViewController` here. A `UIViewController` is used to manage the views displayed to a user, think about it as a single screen of your app. You can embed view controllers in other view controllers, but typically you won't need to do this for basic stuff.

A `UIViewController` has a lifecycle which you can find more about here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652793

Now what it appears like you want to do is to wrap up the functionality of creating a button, you can do this by either creating a factory method in you `ViewController` class (or other class somewhere else), or by subclassing UIButton and creating a convenience initialiser method to create the button with the properties you want (you can also use Swift extensions but I won't go into that here).

Lets look at the simplest method and create a factory method inside your `ViewController` class:

```
// The button method takes a title and a selector (the selector is the method that should be called when the button is tapped)
func makeButton(title: String, action: Selector) -> UIButton {

    // Create a basic button with a default size
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

    // Customise the button with your settings
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

    // Return the newly created button
    return button
}
```

Now we have a method that creates a button of a default size and position, we want to call that method to create a button and then add it as a subview of the `ViewController`'s view. To do that we can do something in the `viewDidLoad()` method that we override:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Always remember to call the super method to ensure all super classes have a chance to do any work thats required by them
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create the button by calling our new method
    let button = self.makeButton(title: "Test Button", action: #selector(buttonTapped))

    // Set the origin of the button to move it to the right position
    button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    // Finally add the new button as a subclass of the view controllers view
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Now we understand whats going on in the methods we can put it all together to have a class that looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = self.makeButton(title: "Test Button", action: #selector(buttonTapped))
        button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func makeButton(title: String, action: Selector) -> UIButton {

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        print("Button tapped")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create new `UIViewController` here:

```
let renderobj = render()
renderobj.sign()
```

but `ViewController` instance is showing in this moment.